# align list of symbols with dash

Tags: indentation, nomenclature

I'm trying to make a list of symbols and I have something like this

```
P --- pressure

eta --- viscosity

lambda(P,T) --- thermal conductivity
```

...

I need to align this list with dash symbol. I tried to make it with `nomencl` package and tabbing but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture this using table. See below:

```
\begin{tabular}{llp{.7\textwidth}}
$P$ &---& pressure\\
$\eta$ &---& viscosity\\
$\lambda(P,T)$ &---& thermal conductivity\\
\end{tabular}
```

> **Note:** I have edited the answer to include `p{<width>}` for long sentences.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I used the variant with tabular, and it works well for short descriptions. Unfortunately I have a long sentences and it doesn't fit to the page and some of them are staying to far from the first symbol. How can I move part of this senteces to the new line with no indent?

Comment: @anatoly you'll need for example a `p{<width>}` type column, see the [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) documentation for details.

Comment: @cgnieder: I have updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 13):

The [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes have a list that basically does what you want:

```
\begin{labeling}[<separator>]{<widest label>}
  ...
\end{labeling}
```

This evironment can be used with the standard classes, too, by loading the `scrextend` package.  The list would then maybe look like:

```
\begin{labeling}[---]{\hspace*{4em}}
  \item[$P$] pressure 
  \item[$\eta$] viscosity
  \item[$\lambda(P,T)$] thermal conductivity
\end{labeling}
```

You can probably make [`nomencl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) use the list and you can definitely customize [`acro`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/acro) or [`glossaries`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) to use it. Here's a way with `acro`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}% only if you don't use a KOMA-Script class
\usepackage{acro}

\newenvironment{myacrolist}
  {\labeling[---]{\hspace*{4em}}}% choose length for widest label
  {\endlabeling}
\acsetup{list-type=myacrolist}

\DeclareAcronym{pressure}{
  short = \ensuremath{P} ,
  long  = pressure ,
  sort  = pressure
}
\DeclareAcronym{viscosity}{
  short = \ensuremath{\eta} ,
  long  = viscosity ,
  sort  = viscosity
}
\DeclareAcronym{therm-conduct}{
  short = \ensuremath{\lambda(P,T)} ,
  long  = thermal conductivity ,
  sort  = conductivity thermal
}
\begin{document}

\acuseall
\printacronyms[name=Nomenclature]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are many ways, the following uses a simple `tabular` (for more than one page, package `longtable` can be used):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}@{ --- }l@{}}
 p & pressure \\
 \eta & viscosity \\
 \lambda(P,T) & thermal conductivity \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The dash symbol is added in the `tabular`'s preamble between the first and second column.
- Math mode is enabled for the first column with the help of package `array` and its specification with `>` and `>`.

Comment: You should probably use `p{<width>}` column type if you have quite long descriptors.

Comment: @Martin: Or `X` of package `tabularx` (or its combinations with `longtable`.