# Can I disable \RequirePackage without modifying a document style?

Tags: floats, packages

I have a custom (provided by someone else, not in latex repos) document style that loads `flafter` package in its style definition by unconditional `\RequirePackage{flafter}`. I want to use this style, but without this particular package. Is there a way to disable or make this package ineffective without actually modifying the style? E.g., by resetting some options in document's preamble?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@flafter.sty\endcsname{}
```

before the package is loaded (this works for any package)

Alternatively just make an empty file

```
 flafter.sty
```

and put it in the same directory/folder as your document, LaTeX will input that instead of the standard one.

Comment: Actually I use LyX to typeset my document, so I'm unable to place this command _before_ the document style is loaded (it seems to be not supported in LyX). Is there something I can do in a preamble (after the style is loaded)?

Comment: @tomash if the flafter package is loaded within the class then it has already made all its redefinitions before the preamble starts. It does not save the old definitions, they have gone.

Comment: alternatively just make an empty file `flafter.sty` and put it in the same directory/folder as your document, latex will input that instead of the standard one. @tomash

Comment: Thank you David very much, it works! It think this is the correct answer to my question.

Comment: @tomash added that comment to the answer

Answer (score 5):

An alternative would be using package `scrlfile` to prevent a package from loading.

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{flafter}
\documentclass{<yourCustomStyle>}
```

More on package `scrlfile` can be found in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165470/37907