# Classicthesis + multiple paragraphs in footnotes

Tags: footnotes, indentation, classicthesis

Some of my footnotes consist of multiple paragraphs. Normally, a new paragraph will be indented just as new paragraphs are indented when they're not in footnotes. In classicthesis, however, something is preventing the indentation in the footnotes, but I can't find what it is.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\deffootnote{0em}{0em}{\thefootnotemark\hspace*{.5em}}
```

in `classicthesis.sty` sets the `parindent` in footnotes to `0em`.

The original definition for KOMA-classes is
`\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}`.
Here, the `parindent` in footnotes is set to `1em`, which is dependant of the font size.  More information on `deffootnote` can be found in the documentation of KOMA-script.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Der Ententeich}
\blindtext\marginpar{Duckweed is yummy}\par
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext\par\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Of course, this approach only works with a KOMA-class as they define `\deffootnote`. Interestingly, for a standard class, the author of `classicthesis` is using another package to style footnotes, didn't bother about the paragraph indentation, but rather typing a message to the terminal, that it is not the same as with a KOMA-class.

Anybody interested in using the KOMA-solution? No problem, we can use package `scrextend`, which [can do quite some more stuff](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165232/37907).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\deffootnote[1em]{1.5em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Der Ententeich}
\blindtext\marginpar{Duckweed is yummy}\par
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext\par\blindtext}
\end{document}
```